# How to use Wagon maven plugin with FTPS

Tags: maven, ftps, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon

I'm using the below configuration to upload files to a remote server through FTPS protocol :

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
        <url>ftps://username:password@ip_address</url>
        <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
        <toDir>.</toDir>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>upload</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If i use only **FTP** instead of **FTPS** in the url parameter the goal is executed successfully and data are sent to the remote server, but when I use **FTPS** for security reasons, I get the below error :

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:upload (default-cli) on project XXX: The parameters 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:upload are missing or invalid
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The parameters 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:upload are missing or invalid
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:641)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:594)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
```

'

Comment: Can you provide the whole exception ?

Comment: There is a typo in your example. There is a double `<` in your URL element within configuration `<<url>ftps://username:password@ip_address</url>`. Not sure if that's a typo in your example or your actual code?

Comment: Updated : whole exception provided @Theo

Comment: The typo was only in my example @SimplyGed

Comment: @aminedev have you tried with `<endpointChecking>false</endpointChecking>` in  configuration?

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy yes i tried it, it's not solving the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue using the below configuration :

Pom.xml :

```
 <extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <configuration>
        <serverId>serverid</serverId>
        <skip>true</skip>
        <url>ftps://ip_address:port</url>
        <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
        <toDir>.</toDir>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>upload</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Settings.xml :

```
   <server>
        <id>serverid</id>
        <username>XXXXXX</username>
        <password>XXXXXX</password>
        <configuration>
            <endpointChecking>false</endpointChecking>
            <securityProtocol>TLS</securityProtocol> 
            <implicit>true</implicit>
            <passiveMode>true</passiveMode>
        </configuration>
    </server>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an ability to test the answer in my environment, but it seems that Wagon supports FTPS mode with FTP provider.

The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ftp/) however states that you should configure the `securityProtocol` to be FTPS for this, since the default is TLS.

```
// settings.xml
<server>
    <id>ftp.server.id</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <configuration>
         ....
         <securityProtocol>FTPS</securityProtocol>   <-- !!!
    </configuration>
</server>
```

Comment: There's an error in documentation, security protocol allows only SSL or TLS values :

      '    /** The use SSL/TLS protocol. */
    private String protocol = DEFAULT_PROTOCOL; '

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently. In my case, because my FTP server's certificate was self-signed, I **did** have to disable `endpointChecking`:

```
<endpointChecking>false</endpointChecking>
```

However, it also appears that the Wagon FTP provider does not support encrypted data connections. I see no mention in [the code](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/wagon-3.5.1/wagon-providers/wagon-ftp/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/ftp/FtpsWagon.java) of

```
FTPSClient.execProt("P");
```

Since I am running `vsftpd` as my FTP server, it was necessary to allow unencrypted data connections server-side as well:

```
# vsftpd.conf 
...
force_local_data_ssl=NO
```

In my case, the use of the `<implicit>` setting was counter-productive, as `vsftpd` by default negotiates the port rather than using the implicit one.